# Pressing back button in Android MainActivity does not destroy the activity anymore. Is it a new feature?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, onbackpressed

When I press the back button in MainActivity the home screen is shown, however onDestroy is not being called. Is it a new feature? Using Emulator Pixel 3A in API 33 arm 64-v8a. The same happens through the phone pixel 6A API 33.
Also local variables are not deleted.

It should have destroyed MainActivity when the back button is pressed

Comment: Hi, there are changes for Android 12 and higher. You can check them here - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack#back-press-behavior

Answer (score 1):

On Android 12+ Devices, back button doesn't result in (main) Activity being `destroyed` instead app will stay in `warm` state, similar to when exiting using home button.

**Reason** behind this change is now user can quickly resume app from a `warm` state, instead of having to completely restart the app from a `cold` state.

If you want it function like before then there are two workaround that you can use:

```
 1. Using AndroidX Activity APIs

 2. By overriding onBackPressed()
```